# Is there a way to adjust hue absolutely in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

From my understanding, when I use Color -> Hue-Chroma or Hue-Saturation, and slide Hue value, it adds this value to the hue of every pixel in the selection.

What I want is to just "colorize" the picture by setting every pixel's hue to the same value, like adjusting absolute value, not relative.

It would also be wonderful if there would be a way to do the same for saturation and lightness.

How could I do that?

Comment: Hopefully not all three at the same time… that would be better achieved with an empty document & the paint bucket ;)

Comment: There's an adjustment for that. *Colors > Colorize*.  Hue, Saturation and Lightness sliders are available in the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Try Color > Colorize for a start. Luminance differences stay, so you will see still colorfulness differences. That's because the same saturation means different colorfulness at different luminance levels.

You can apply "curves" to adjust luminance levels.

Answer (score 0):

Add a layer, set it to blend mode `LCh Hue` (or `HSV hue`). Bucket fill with the color from which you want the hue:

[image]

There are similar blend modes for Saturation/Chroma and Lightness. The "Color" ones are a combination of Hue and Saturation/Chroma.